# Why is this Typescript object not assignable to generic type T, which is a Union including the type of the object

Tags: typescript, generics

Obviously a contrived example, but why am I unable to assign an object of type ISpeaker3 to a generic type T that is a union including ISpeaker3? And why is there a need for the double cast shown below.

```
interface ISpeaker {
    greeting: string;
    speak: Function;
}

interface ISpeaker1 extends ISpeaker {
    introduction: string;
    firstArgument: string;
}

interface ISpeaker2 extends ISpeaker {
    secondArgument: string;
}

interface ISpeaker3 extends ISpeaker {
    rebuttal: string;
}

class Speaker3 implements ISpeaker3 {
    public greeting: string = "hello I'm Speaker Three."
    public rebuttal: string = "what a lot of nonsense!"
    speak(){console.log(this.greeting + this.rebuttal)}
}

class Debate<T extends ISpeaker | ISpeaker3> {
    speakers: Array<T>
    randomSpeaker: T
    constructor(spkrs: Array<T>) {
        for (let s of spkrs) {
            if (s.constructor.name === 'Speaker3') {
                (s as ISpeaker3).rebuttal = "Some other argument..." // OK. 
                let tempSpeaker = s as ISpeaker as ISpeaker3 // OK, but why the double cast necessary?
                this.randomSpeaker = tempSpeaker // Error - ISpeaker3 is not assignable to type T
            }
            else this.randomSpeaker = s // OK
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The explanation could be find here:

#### [Narrowing breaking changes #7662](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7662)

Let me cite:

> Type narrowing does not work for captured variables in functions and    class expressions
>
> ```
> export class Class {
>     constructor(public p) { }
> }
>
> var c: Class | string;
> var x: Class;
>
> if (c instanceof Class) {
>     function inner() {
>         x = c; // Error, type of c is not narrowed, c is Class | string
>     }
>     x = c; // OK, c is Class
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `let tempSpeaker = s as T & ISpeaker3;`